# ASP.NET What reference am I missing for Parameter Direction and SQLDBType

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sqlparameter

Hey just wondering what references I need to add to my VS2008 Project to get the  following working

Name `ParameterDirection` is not declared.
Name `SqlDbType` is not declared

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ensuring that your project has a reference to the `System.Data` assembly

[image]

and that your code file has:

```
using System.Data;
```

That should give you access to both those enumeration types.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these enumeration ([ParameterDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx) and [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx))are defined in System.Data.dll
This library is not referenced by default in some types of projects.
Did you `Add reference` for it?
If yes, then provide some code, please.